# Finding bridge edges more efficiently than Tarjan's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms

I have to find a bridge edge in a graph but have to find it efficient time complexity.

Is there an algorithm that is better than Tarjan's Bridge-finding algorithm?

Comment: Did you [try to search for one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)#Tarjan.27s_Bridge-finding_algorithm)? Before asking questions, we expect you to do some research, and share what you have tried.

Comment: I know it , but i want to know that is there  also other algorithms with better time complexity?

Comment: Ad your edit: why change "efficiently" to "efficient time complexity"? It doesn't say more, and is in fact slightly wrong. *Problems* have complexities, algorithms have costs.

Answer (score 2):

Schmidt [1] gives another algorithm based on chain decompositions (see the Introduction of [1] for even more algorithms). The algorithm runs in linear time, just like Tarjan's algorithm. Asymptotically, there is no faster algorithm for the problem, since reading the input already takes linear time. If you are interested in finding bridges *in practice*, it is best you experiment with both Tarjan's algorithm and the one in [1] with your specific data.

If you want a sublinear algorithm (i.e. faster than Tarjan's or the one in [1]), you must not read the whole input.

---

[1] [Schmidt, Jens M. "A simple test on 2-vertex-and 2-edge-connectivity." Information Processing Letters 113.7 (2013): 241-244.](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.0700.pdf)